# Setting Contract level variables

Tags: state-variable

I'm a Python Developer jumping into Solidity and I feel like I'm missing something about variables and scope.

How do I set and access variables outside of a function's scope?

I can't seem to add spins ( simple uint ) to my spin history ( uint[] ) and access them elsewhere. I can use push and get it in an array within the same function, but it doesn't update the State level variable.

```
contract GoldenEgg{
uint[] public spinHistory;


function spin() constant returns (uint) {
    uint spin = uint8(uint256(keccak256(block.timestamp, block.difficulty))%37);
    addToHistory(spin);
    return spin;
}

function getHistory() constant returns (uint[]) {
    return spinHistory;
}

function addToHistory( uint spin ) constant returns (uint[]) {
   spinHistory.push(spin); 
   return spinHistory;
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spin()` is marked `constant` (a deprecated alias for `view`). So it can't change any state. When you call a `view` function, instead of sending a transaction to the network, you just ask one node (the one you're connected to) to run the code and tell you the result. No changes are persisted or stored in the blockchain.

If you remove `constant`, you'll send a transaction instead when you call that function. It will take longer to execute and won't actually return you a result, but the state changes you make will persist.